# How to make flex-grow ignore padding?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

These are my first steps with flex and I have the following code:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1241px;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 5;
  background-color: cyan;
}

input {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 13;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 6;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <label>width must = 258.54px</label>
  <input type="text" value="width must = 672.20px">
  <div>width must = 310.25px</div>
</div>
```

Everything works as expected. However, I need to add to my input `padding-left: 25px` and as only I do it all sizes of the elements inside flexbox change. How can I add this padding and at the same keep the sizes (I mean using my solution with flex-grow and flex-basis)?

This is what I have with `padding:0`:

[image]

This is what I have when I add `padding-left: 25px`:

[image]

Comment: if you change in input class `padding:0` to `padding-left:25px;` is not the result you need?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, No, then the width of label, input and div change

Comment: You're saying you need fixed widths (in the written content), and then you're using `flex-grow` and `flex-basis: 0`. That's not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *How to make `flex-grow` ignore `padding`?*

`flex-grow` cannot ignore `padding`:

- `flex-grow` consumes free space.
- `padding` occupies space.
- So `flex-grow` must factor in `padding` in order to work properly.

Here's a workaround that may be useful to you:

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1241px;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  flex: 5 1 0;
  background-color: cyan;
}

#input {
  flex: 13 1 0;
  height: 100%;
}

input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 25px;
  background-color: yellow;
  border: none;
}

div:last-child {
  flex: 6 1 0;
  background-color: red;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <label>width must = 258.54px</label>
  <div id="input"><input type="text" value="width must = 672.20px"></div>
  <div>width must = 310.25px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you take a look at this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62681309/how-to-make-input-fit-grid-columns ?

Comment: The content also occupies space but is ignored (so you can change the content and the width stays the same), this happens *because* you set flex-basis to 0. But apparently flex-basis: 0 is after the padding, we would want it to be before (because it has box-sizing: border-box and the padding is, by definition, inside the element so shouldn't affect what is outside it).

Answer (score 2):

since it's a text input, use text-indent instead of padding:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1241px;
  height: 30px;
}

label {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 5;
  background-color: cyan;
}

input {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 13;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}

div {
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 6;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <label>width must = 258.54px</label>
  <input type="text" value="width must = 672.20px">
  <div>width must = 310.25px</div>
</div>
<div class="flexbox">
  <label>width must = 258.54px</label>
  <input type="text" value="width must = 672.20px" style="text-indent: 25px;">
  <div>width must = 310.25px</div>
</div>
```