# How to make input fit grid columns?

Tags: html, css

These are my first steps in grid and this is my code:

```css
.grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(24, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: 30px;
        grid-column-gap: 10px;
        grid-row-gap: 10px;
        max-width:1241px;
    }

    label {
        background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="grid">
      <label style="grid-column: 1/6; grid-row: 1;">Label</label>
       <input style="grid-column: 6/8; grid-row: 1;" type="text" value="input 1">
       <input style="grid-column: 13/25; grid-row: 1;" type="text" value="input 2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you see input 1 width is almost equal to label width, but label takes 5 columns (1 - 6) but input 1 only 2 columns (6 - 8). At the same time the width of the grid columns must be equal. How to make input 1 fit into these two columns and not to exceed it?

Comment: Your code is rendering properly. It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Paulie_D I want the width of the input 1 to be equal to two column widths. I mean input 1.width = column6.width + column7.width.

Comment: Why would it be half? The first spans 6 columns the second 2,,,,that's not half.

Comment: @Paulie_D As I understad the first spans 5 columns ([1-5]). I meant about half. But look at the picture, do you see this relation?

Comment: Either way 2 is not half of 5